# How to access class variable inside of jquery event?

Tags: typescript

If I'm inside a jQuery event, I'm not sure how I can access class variables. Example below

```
// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

export class Notes {

    // I want to access this inside of the click event
    test = "test";

    foo() {
        //works here
        alert(this.test);

        $("#testDiv").click(function () {

            // context of this changes so this no longer works
            alert(this.test);

            // How do I access the test variable in here?
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the lambda expression, it binds `this` to the enclosing scope's `this`.

```
export class Notes {
    private test: string = "test";

    foo() {
        //works here
        alert(this.test);

        $("#testDiv").click(() => {
            alert(this.test);
        })
    }
}
```

is translated into

```
var Notes = (function () {
    function Notes() {
        this.test = "test";
    }
    Notes.prototype.foo = function () {
        var _this = this;
        alert(this.test);
        $("#testDiv").click(function () {
            alert(_this.test);
        });
    };
    return Notes;
})();
exports.Notes = Notes;
```

Be careful however, inside the jQuery callback you will not be able to access the DOMElement as expected, since `this` is translated. If you want to be able to do both, add `this` to a variable in the closure yourself:

```
export class Notes {
    private test: string = "test";

    foo() {
        alert(this.test);
        var self = this;
        $("#testDiv").click(function() {
            alert(self.test);
            $(this).hide(); // still works
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way that works however I feel like there is probably a better way?

```
export class Notes {
    test = "test";

    foo() {
        var self = this;

        $("#testDiv").click(function () {
            alert(self.test);
        })
    }
}
```